# How does autoscaling effect Crons for a django application

Tags: cron, openshift

When I create an Openshift Django application with autoscaling and minutely running crons, are the cron tasks ran on each scaled instance or just once for the cluster of instances. I've got a cron that triggers a database heavy task and only want to run one task at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cron cartridge is scaled alongside the the web cartridges.  So each cron will fire on each web server.  You might look into controlling them with a database table or something so they can mark when they have fired so no other ones fire.